Hadoop : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute
I am using this command for word count in Command Prompt in Windows
hadoop jar "C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.4.0.jar" wordcount /newdir/HadoopSmall.txt /newdir/smallword

and getting this error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute 

My Hadoop Version is 3.4.0
Java Version JDK 1.8.*

No one really runs mapreduce anymore. Why do you need this command vs using something similar in Spark (since you had the tag, but you're not actually using it here)

@OneCricketeer Actually, I am following a training material and there it was included in my course for practice.

This question is similar to: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw- (on Windows). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Sudhanshukumar How old is that video? What version of Hadoop is it using? Can you link here?

This is the video link:[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knAS0w-jiUk&pp=ygUaI2hhZG9vcGluc3RhbGxhdGlvbndpbmRvd3M%3D]
It is using hadoop 3.2.4

If you want to follow along, please use the same versions as them, as well as Java 11, since that is what Hadoop officially supports. However, as mentioned, you should not be installing Hadoop to run Mapreduce. This all runs direct from an IDE/terminal - https://github.com/OneCricketeer/mapreduce-sandbox
